# Swift What is the best way to replace content in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to do something like in the GIF
I tried 2 ways, one was hiding the elements on selecting the row and showing others, but that's not really elegant and doesn't work very well
and second was creating 2 views, one with labels, another with buttons, adding them as subviews to cell.contentView but that caused some issues with other cells as they were displaying wrong data. How can I recreate something like this?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this would work. But can you try self.view.layoutfNeeded() after you have added another view as subview. and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I would create a view that is the size of the content view and out all of the labels in that and a second view the size of the content view (probably a UIstackView) containing the buttons and set constraints so that the button containing view was initially offscreen, to the right of the content view. Then using a long press recognizer, animate the constraints so that the buttons slide in and the labels are pushed out. Personally I think a long press recogniser has discoverability issues, so I would put a button, like … or something to trigger the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

1. Use 2 different UITableViewCells: add them to the table view in your storyboard and design them separately, also you can use 2 different UITableViewCell subclasses for them
2. Have an array in the tableview's datasource class that will define the type of the cell from each row (e.g. the simplest solution would be an array of integers, with values: 0 representing the first cell, 1 representing the second cell)
3. Initialise that array with 0s for each row
4. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` :

   - if cellTypes[indexPath.row] == 0  --> return a cell of first type
   - if cellTypes[indexPath.row] == 1  --> return a cell of the second type
5. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` :

   - switch the cell type in the array
   - reload the row with animation, e.g. you can use .fade or .left or .right etc.

`tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`

EDIT: Your solution is also a good one, but it can cause problems when the cells are dequeued, so if a cell with the wrong subviews is dequeued then you need to switch the subviews back in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` datasource method.

EDIT2: I took some time and I have tried my solution in Xcode. Here is the code of my tableview controller:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var cellTypes: [Int] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.cellTypes.count
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56.0
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if self.cellTypes[indexPath.row] == 1 {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        } else {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)
        }
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if self.cellTypes[indexPath.row] == 1 {
            self.cellTypes[indexPath.row] = 2
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else {
            self.cellTypes[indexPath.row] = 1
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
        }
    }

}
```

And here is how it is working in the iOS simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are on the right track about creating 2 separate views inside the cell; one for showing 3 buttons (Play Now, Play Next etc.) and, one for showing the song's details (song name, singer name etc.).

In order not to mess with frames or constraints (in case you are using Autolayout), the main trick here is to create *a snapshot* of the view containing the buttons and move it to the end of the cell.

As I said above, you should have 2 separate views. I'll call them:

- **infoView**: View that has 2 labels showing the song's and the singer's name.
- **actionsView**: View that has 3 buttons for play actions. (Now, Next, Last etc.)

Here are things that you should do when user taps on a cell:

1. Check if cell is not selected. If it is not, then hide **infoView** and show **actionView**.
2. If cell is selected:

   - Deselect the cell.
   - Create a snapshot out of **actionsView**, set its frame accordingly so it'll shadow the real **actionsView**.
   - Set **actionView**'s **isHidden** property to **true**.
   - Set **infoView**'s **isHidden** property to **false**.
   - Set **frame.origin.x** value of the snapshot to **contentView**'s **maxX** in an animation block so it'll move to the right side of the cell smoothly.
   - At the end of the animation, remove the snapshot from view hierarchy.

I've created a cell class and defined a method that executes those steps:

```
public class SongCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var infoView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var actionsView: UIView!

  ...

  public func showActions(_ show: Bool) {
    switch show {
    case true:
      infoView.isHidden = true
      actionsView.isHidden = false

    case false:
      if let snapshot = actionsView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {
        snapshot.frame = actionsView.frame
        contentView.addSubview(snapshot)

        actionsView.isHidden = true
        infoView.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
          snapshot.frame.origin.x = self.contentView.frame.maxX

        }, completion: { _ in
          snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
        })
      }
      else {
        infoView.isHidden = false
        actionsView.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks on my simulator:

[image]

You can download the project from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x9hsqvd38cmmm57/AADyzLPI3cz4BQJBsLrOErjma?dl=0).